# Fixed position on a mobile browser

Tags: css, mobile

Hi i have an issue, i want to a bar that stays at the bottom of the page i have it working on a real web browser with the following code.

```
bottom:0;
position:fixed;
```

It works well on the web, but when it gets to mobile, it doesn't do same. What do i do.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about Mobile Safari (on iPhone/iPad/etc), it has an unusual definition of what is the "viewport" and therefore how "fixed" works. You have to use a workaround. See [this blog post](http://doctyper.com/archives/200808/fixed-positioning-on-mobile-safari/) (and the links contained therein) for details.